# Converting a select query to an update query - Numbering Rows Per Group

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a select query that appends a column of sequential/incremental numbering that restarts at 1 for every change in `Album`. It is based on [this tutorial](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/02/how-to-number-rows-in-mysql/)

```
set @vAlbum = '';
set @vnum  = 1;

SELECT 
    Song,
    Album,
    @vnum:=IF(@vAlbum = Album, @vnum + 1, 1) AS row_number,
    @vAlbum:=Album AS dummy
FROM
    tablename
```

How can this be modified so that it's an update query, where instead of creating a column `row_number`, it updates the column `TrackNum`?

Desired outcome:

```
Album|Song|TrackNum
Hits1|AAAA|1
Hits1|BBBB|2
Hits1|CCCC|3
Hits2|AAAA|1
Hits2|BBBB|2
Hits3|AAAA|1
Hits3|BBBB|2
Hits3|CCCC|3
Hits3|DDDD|4
```

Comment: Maybe, it is better to set the increment sequence in application side if you have.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comment

Comment: @Avidos Why do it outside the db when it's perfectly possible to do it as a query directly?

Comment: That's why I used the word 'Maybe' for it is a suggestion. Because in my experience so far, putting the logic of the system in the application side as much as possible. @jpw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you want (tested with MySQL 5.6.17):

```
SET @Album = '';
SET @num  = 1;

UPDATE tablename t,
    (SELECT 
        Song,
        Album,
        @num := IF(@Album = Album, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
        @Album := Album AS dummy
    FROM
        tablename) t2 
SET 
    t.TrackNum = t2.row_number
WHERE
    t.album = t2.album AND t.song = t2.song;
```

Note that the order the songs gets numbered might be random and maybe you want to add an `ORDER BY Album, Song ASC` or something similar to fix the order (if so it should be added to the end of the derived table).

Sample output:

```
Album   Song  TrackNum
Hits1   AAAA    1
Hits1   BBBB    2
Hits1   CCCC    3
Hits2   AAAA    1
Hits2   BBBB    2
Hits3   AAAA    1
Hits3   BBBB    2
Hits3   CCCC    3
Hits3   DDDD    4
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. I'm about to test it. Just a quick question. Why would the numbering be off? The original table is ordered by a key, ID. And the tracks are all in order. It's just that the TrackNum data is corrupted. Does this matter?

Comment: @square_eyes Most relational databases returns unordered sets of data if you don't include a `order by` statement. If you have an ordered key like ID you might want to alter the query to order by it, or possibly add it to the derived table and the outer where clause.

Comment: Thank you and thank you. It worked. This is very cool and I've learned something in that you can make a temp table select and copy across the results. For the record I added an ordered bit too.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the `UPDATE` query below to achieve your goal. And be sure to specify the row or rows you want to update by adding a `WHERE` clause. See below:

```
SELECT @i := 0;
UPDATE tablename SET TrackNum= (SELECT @i := @i + 1) 
WHERE Album = 'Hits1';
```

Comment: I don't see how this will sequentially add numbers, and restart at 1, for every change in `Album`.

Comment: Won't this set all the TrackNum fields to 1?

Comment: This will only work for one set of incremental numbers. I have many Albums. See the desired outcome in the question. I need the numbers to restart at 1 for each album.

Comment: I revised my `WHERE` clause. try it again.

Comment: `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'tablename' for update in FROM clause`